# JS and css not working in angular 5, on go to next router

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular5

In angular 5 projects when I am going to next route CSS and js not working and when I reload the page it's working properly it happen the same thing when I clicked in the router and after reloading the page it's working perfectly.
    I am loading all CSS and js files in and the code is here.

> .angular-cli.json

```
 "styles": [
    "assets/css/jquery/jquery-ui.min.css",
    "assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css",
    "assets/css/fontawesome/font-awesome.min.css",
    "assets/css/summernote/summernote.css",
    "assets/css/nvd3/nv.d3.css",
    "assets/css/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css",
    "assets/css/dropzone/dropzone.css",
    "assets/css/animate/animate.min.css",
    "assets/css/mcustomscrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css",
    "assets/css/theme-default.css",
    "../node_modules/froala-editor/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css",
    "../node_modules/froala-editor/css/froala_style.min.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
    "styles.scss"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "assets/js/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js",
    "assets/js/plugins/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js",
    "../node_modules/froala-editor/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js",
    "assets/js/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js",
    "assets/js/plugins/icheck/icheck.min.js",
    "assets/js/plugins/mcustomscrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js",
    "assets/js/plugins/morris/raphael-min.js",
    "assets/js/plugins/scrolltotop/scrolltopcontrol.js",
    "assets/js/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
    "assets/js/plugins/owl/owl.carousel.min.js",
    "assets/js/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
    "assets/js/plugins/tableexport/tableExport.js",
    "assets/js/moment.min.js",
    "assets/js/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js",
    "assets/js/settings.js",
    "assets/js/plugins.js",
    "assets/js/actions.js"
   ],
```

And another routes details are here, i have try to write code into index.html and styles.scss but not working same issue, when i click any route its not working, when i refresh page all things are working perfect.

and route something like this and there is no any error during the compile time.

> app-routing.module.ts

```
{ path: 'officers', component: OfficersListComponent},
```

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: No there is no error in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, it can be solved by two methods one is included js file in index.html, but expert says that never add js file in index.html because load and security issue occurred, I don't know how still I am finding an expert. 
then another method is based on the component.

```
ngOnInit() {
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.getScript('../../assets/frontend/js/app.js', function (w) { });
}); }
```

this will always help and in page load also load js file, also you can include Jquery its working perfect.